# Удаление определенного количества байт с конца файла shell скрипт

Tags: linux, shell

Добрый день. Собственно вопрос. Как средствами shell удалить с конца файла N - о количество символов. 
Есть зашифрованный gpg файл. В конец его дописываем контрольную сумму. 
А затем ее нужно считать и удалить. Как?

пробовал средствами  sed но так и не дошел до рабочего варианта

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пусть в переменных `n` - длина контрольной суммы, `file` - имя файла.

```
truncate -s $(( $(stat -c '%s' $file) - $n )) $file
```