# Удаление n символов из начала файла зашифрованого gpg используя Shell

Tags: linux, shell

Стоит задача удаления `n` числа символов из начала файла используя `shell`. Файл зашифрован `gpg`. Файл нельзя перезаписывать в другой файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dd if=$file of=$file skip=$n iflag=skip_bytes conv=notrunc
```

Далее см.
[Удаление определенного количества байт с конца файла shell скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477882/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-shell-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82/477897#477897)

Comment: Да так и сделал, хотя чуть раньше чем увидел ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для обрезания можно использовать cut. Например, для удаления первых 10 символов:

```
cut -c 10- fname.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: нельзя перезаписывать зашифрованный файл. Особое требование

Comment: @Sebefour противоречите себе :)

Comment: cut удалит из каждой строки, а не из начала файла

Comment: Хм, да, Вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Инлайном можно попытаться так:

```
sed -i '1s/^.\{10\}//' fname.txt
```

но валидно только для текстовых файлов.